# Selenium ChromeDriver - element never got visible

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I try to send keys to input field but can't do it...
I have tried different ways to wait till element is visible but got timeout exceptions...

```
IWebElement userName = driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserName"));
IWebElement userPassword = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password"));
IWebElement subButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(("//button[contains(.,'Вхід')]")));
while (true)
{
    userName = driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserName"));
    if (userName.Displayed)
    {
        userName.SendKeys("test");
        break;
    }
}
subButton.Click();
```

Using this method gives me always timeout:

```
public static void WaitForElementLoad(By by, int timeoutInSeconds)
{
    if (timeoutInSeconds > 0)
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(by));
    }
}
```

Comment: It is hard to answer without examining this site and looking at HTML code. Some tips: check if `id=UserName` is unique within the page, in theory it must be unique, but the developer may not know this and added two elements with the same id `UserName`.

Comment: The obvious conclusion seems to be that the element is not visible. Check your locators and make sure they are unique and locate the element you intended.

Comment: Please share HTML or URL\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its hidden just send/execute a simple js by selenium that will show the element. But it cant be a little bit more tricki. Set the window size to a bigger one eg 2000x2000. If something is not placed in the viewport selenium will not see it.

Answer (score 0):

please try to use JavaScript to scroll to the element and then perform other operations on the element

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```